# Weird matplotlib color issue when plotting line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I might be missing something very obvious here, but I've tried numerous combinations I haven't been able to find the reason for this behavior.

I'm running Python v2.7.6 and matplotlib v1.4.3.

I have a simple plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x, y = np.random.random(50), np.random.random(50)
plt.plot(x, y, c='red', ls='-', lw=1., label='a', zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

Notice that the color is supposed to be red as per `c='red'`. What I get instead is:

[image]

If I use the full name of the argument `color='red'`, the line is red as it should. If I remove *any* of the arguments after `c='red'`, e.g.:

```
plt.plot(x, y, c='red', ls='-', lw=1., label='a')
plt.plot(x, y, c='red', ls='-', lw=1., zorder=2)
plt.plot(x, y, c='red', ls='-', label='a', zorder=2)
plt.plot(x, y, c='red', lw=1., label='a', zorder=2)
```

the plotted line is **also** red.

Am I doing something very obviously wrong here or did I stumble into a weird issue?

---

**Add**:

Using:

```
plt.plot(x, y, c='r', ls='-', lw=1., label='a', zorder=2)
```

as proposed (i.e.: `c='r'` instead of `c='red'`) has no effect on my system, I still get the blue line.

Comment: You're not suppose to write `c='red'`, it's `c='r'`

Comment: Writing `c='r'` changes nothing in my system, I still get a blue line.

Comment: @FreddieV4 it should work just fine with c='red'. Notice that it works when one of the arguments is taken away. Also, it's in the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html). "Finally, legal html names for colors, like ‘red’, ‘burlywood’ and ‘chartreuse’ are supported."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and the fix will be released with v1.5.0.

See issue at Github for more details: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5197

Answer (score 1):

The following information work with Python 3.x and matplotlib 1.4.3

`c='r'` found in [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x, y = np.random.random(50), np.random.random(50)
plt.plot(x, y, c='r', ls='-', lw=1., label='a', zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As it seems `color='red'` and `color='r'` seem to work along with `c='r'`. `c='red'` does not change the line color.

Comment: Nope, this has no effect on my system. what versions of Python and matplotlib are you running?

Comment: Also in the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html). "Finally, legal html names for colors, like ‘red’, ‘burlywood’ and ‘chartreuse’ are supported."

Comment: Python 3.4. `c='red'` doesn't work for me, `c=r` does. Running same version of mpl as you.

Comment: try `color='red'` or `color='r'`

Comment: @Leb as I said in the question, I already know that using `color='red'` works and as I've commented above, using `c='r'` has no effect on my system. Perhaps its something that was fixed in v3 of Python.

Comment: @Gabriel yes possibly. It'd be worthwhile looking into bug issues on github or opening one if it doesn't exist. But seeing other methods work, opening the issue isn't worthwhile IMO

Comment: Leb, as @SirParselot stated, using `'r'` or `'red` should be indistinct. Could you modify your answer so that the version of Python and matplotlib are clearly stated?

Comment: Well, if something is not working as expected, that's an issue and should be reported as such. What I'm not sure still is if this is in fact an issue and not something working as it should that I don't know about.

Comment: @Gabriel I stated the proper versions for both. I'll look into github as well and running on different OS to see if it changes the output. I also have python 2.7 on a ubuntu machine to test